# Columns into rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i would like to ask for help please in sql, I have a table in this form

```
ID    | Indicator1 | Indicator2 | Indicator3 | Indicator4
1     | 1          | 0          | 0          | 0
2     | 0          | 1          | 1          | 0
3     | 1          | 1          | 0          | 0
4     | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0
```

And I would like to make it look like this

```
ID    | Indicators
1     | Indicator1
2     | Indicator2
2     | Indicator3
3     | Indicator1
3     | Indicator2
4     | NULL
```

Any suggestions please ? Thank you

Comment: What DB are you using?  It makes a difference on pivot questions.  Technically you are asking for an 'unpivot' here.

Comment: Should point out that pivot/unpivot is the number one sql question asked on here and there is a silly number of previous questions that will answer this for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: i'm using sql server

Answer (score 0):

Use UNPIVOT.

```
SELECT p.Id,
   p.Indicators,
   p.IndicatorsValue 
FROM TableName
UNPIVOT
(
    IndicatorsValue FOR Indicators IN (Indicator1,Indicator2,Indicator3,Indicator4) 
)AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   b.* from #temp a left join (
SELECT p.Id,
   p.Indicators
FROM #temp
UNPIVOT
(
    IndicatorsValue FOR Indicators IN (Indicator1,Indicator2,Indicator3,Indicator4) 
)AS p
where p.IndicatorsValue <>0)b on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: replace #temp with your table name

Answer (score 0):

Use UNPIVOT and add filter to remove unnecessary columns:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ID, Indicators
FROM #Indicator
UNPIVOT (IndicatorsValue
FOR Indicators IN (Indicator1,Indicator2,Indicator3,Indicator4)) AS up
WHERE up.IndicatorsValue <> 0
```